# Why Lowess return an y with 'NA' for each x?

Tags: r, loess

I was trying to run a lowess function and then plot the results. After I run the lowess function, all the y values I got are 'NA'. There is no warning or error was shown for this procedure until I proceed to run the plot function. Could anyone give me a hint why the lowess produced the y with only 'NA'?

```
mammo = lowess(temp$THRESHOLDRESULT_S ~ temp$AGEMAMMO_CONTRA,f = 1/2, iter = 10)
plot(mammo, xlab=" ", ylab=NA, axes=F, type="l", lwd=2, lty=2)
```

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: presumably you have an NA in your input data, but cannot help much without the data. Please edit your question to include enough data to make your problem reproducible

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a minimal input data set that will reproduce your error.